# MySQL Trigger perform insert and update

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL after insert trigger that inserts values from an inventory table into an inventory audit table and this works fine.  I need to add another step to the trigger and not having much luck.  In addition to the insert into the audit table, in the original table, I need to update a column 'createdby' with the value from 'modifiedby'.

Here is the trigger that works.  I'm hoping someone can help me modify this to add the update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mtenclosures.inventory__ai AFTER INSERT ON mtenclosures.inventory FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO mtenclosures.inventory_archive SELECT 'insert', NULL, NOW(), d.* 
FROM mtenclosures.inventory AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;
```

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE TRIGGER mtenclosures.inventory__ai AFTER INSERT ON mtenclosures.inventory
FOREACH ROW
INSERT INTO mtenclosures.inventory_archive(/column names of mt.inventory_archive)
VALUES(
SELECT 'insert', NULL, NOW(), d.* 
FROM mtenclosures.inventory AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;);
```

This should work.

Hoe this helps....

Comment: I don't believe this will accomplish what I need.  The create trigger that I provided works perfectly for inserting the row into the inventory_archive table.  What I also need it to be able to update the createdby column with the value of the modifiedby column for the inventory table itself, not the inventory_archive table.  so I somehow need to incorporate a update inventory set createdby = modifiedby into that trigger.

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?